# Run a app in background using service

Tags: java, android, service

I am a beginner in android development . I am trying to develop a pedometer app which will count steps even when the app closes. I am using service but still whenever i press back button all steps count reset . What should i do? Thanks in advance .

MainActivity.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    steps=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.step_value);
    distance=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_value);
    skbar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    tsen=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    calories=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories_value);
    sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        date= sdf.parse(reset_time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    current=System.currentTimeMillis();
    skbar.setProgress(10);

    skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onSeekBarListener);
    threshold=10;
    tsen.setTag(String.valueOf(threshold));

    prevy=0;
    presenty=0;
    step=0;

    accelaration=0.00f;
    enableAccelerometer();  
    if(current==set)
    {
        steps.setText(0);
    }
}
public void enableAccelerometer(){        
    sensormanager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensormanager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensormanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),sensormanager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener=new SensorEventListener() { 

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float x=event.values[0];
        float y=event.values[1];
        float z=event.values[2];

        presenty=y;

        if(Math.abs(presenty-prevy)>threshold)
                {
                    step++;
                    steps.setText(String.valueOf(step));
                    x=step/3;
                    miles=x*(float)0.001;
                    distance.setText(String.valueOf(miles));


                }



                prevy=y;


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};



private OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarListener=new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        threshold=skbar.getProgress();
        tsen.setText(String.valueOf(threshold));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
protected ServiceConnection mServerConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

    }


};

public void start() {
    // mContext is defined upper in code, I think it is not necessary to explain what is it 
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Myservice.class);
    mContext.bindService(i, mServerConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mContext.startService(i);
}

public void stop() {
    mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, Myservice.class));
    mContext.unbindService(mServerConn);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {

    case R.id.reset:
    step=0;
    steps.setText(String.valueOf(step));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and this is my Myservice class

```
public class Myservice extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"Pedometer running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Pedometer Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: you should remove this mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, Myservice.class)); from onStop() to run service in background

Comment: Read this first http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html . all you want to know about service is there

Comment: I remove the line . But it still not working .

Comment: now the service will run in the background

Comment: Why i got the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting the service but you are doing all the things in activity. so what ever you have to do in background should be inside the service.

you can start reading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

also refer these examples

1. [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)
2. [javatechgig](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android)

Comment: So i have to use onSensorChangelistner in Myserice class?

Comment: if you want to access it in background, you have to

Comment: Thank you very much , sorry i was unable vote your answer .

Comment: you can accept the answer if it answers your question